# Объединение двух классов типа "enemy" в один. Java

Tags: java, awt

Передо мной стоит задача объединить 2 класса типа Enemy в один, для более удобного использования. Допустим BasicEnemy и SmartEnemy нужно объединить в один, для более правильной иерархии, а как это сделать, ума не приложу, помогите.

```
    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class BasicEnemy extends GameObject {

    private Handler handler;

    public BasicEnemy(float x, float y, ID id, Handler handler) {
        super(x, y, id);
        velX = 5;
        velY = 5;
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return new Rectangle((int)x,(int) y, 16, 16);
    }

    public void tick() {
        x += velX;
        y += velY;
        if(y <= 0 || y >= Game.HEIGHT - 48) velY *= -1;
        if(x <= 0 || x >= Game.WIDTH - 20) velX *= -1;
        handler.addObject(new Trail(x, y, ID.Trail, Color.red, 16, 16, 0.02f, handler));
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect((int)x, (int)y, 16, 16);

    }
}
```

Первый совместить со вторым. Спаун система происходит подобным образом:

```
handler.addObject(new SmartEnemy(r.nextInt(Game.WIDTH - 50), r.nextInt(Game.HEIGHT - 50), ID.FastEnemy, handler));
```

Где в Handler создан список объектов.

Второй класс, который нужно объединить с первым:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class SmartEnemy extends GameObject {

    private Handler handler;
    private GameObject player;

    public SmartEnemy(int x, int y, ID id, Handler handler) {
        super(x, y, id);
        this.handler = handler;
        for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
            if(handler.object.get(i).getId() == ID.Player) player = handler.object.get(i);
        }
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, 16, 16);
    }

    public void tick() {
        x += velX;
        y += velY;

        float diffX = x - player.getX() - 8;
        float diffY = y - player.getY() - 8;
        float distance = (float) Math.sqrt((x-player.getX())*(x-player.getX()) + (y - player.getY())*(y-player.getY()));

        velX = (float) ((-1.0/distance) * diffX);
        velY = (float) ((-1.0/distance) * diffY);

        //This is for not going out of borders
        if(y <= 0 || y >= Game.HEIGHT - 48) velY *= -1;
        if(x <= 0 || x >= Game.WIDTH - 20) velX *= -1;

        handler.addObject(new Trail(x, y, ID.Trail, Color.green, 16, 16, 0.02f, handler));
    }

    //Make their color and size
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect((int)x, (int)y, 16, 16);

    }

}
```

Сам класс handler, если нужен:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Handler {

    LinkedList<GameObject> object = new LinkedList<GameObject>();

    public void tick(){
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);
            tempObject.tick();
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);
            tempObject.render(g);
        }
    }

    public void clearEnemys(){
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);
            object.clear();
            if (Game.gameState != Game.STATE.End)
            addObject(new Player((int)tempObject.getX(), (int)tempObject.getY(), ID.Player, this));
        }
    }
    public void deleteEnemy(ID id){
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);
            if(tempObject.getId() == id){
                removeObject(tempObject);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addObject(GameObject object){
        this.object.add(object);
    }

    public void removeObject(GameObject object){
        this.object.remove(object);
    }

}
```

**--Update--**

Кто-то уже говорит, что у них разное поведение и так далее...
Я прошу помочь мне сделать из них не 2 разных класса (у меня их гораздо больше), а неким образом ОБЪЕДИНИТЬ ИХ в один!

Comment: Зачем Вам тогда два этих класса по отдельности? Не проще создать один класс, описывающий эти два класса? Если нет, попробуйте использовать делегирование

Comment: Объясните зачем нужно их объединять. В данном контексте у них разное поведение.

Comment: Если этот вопрос связан с Вашей предыдущей темой, то Вы несколько не поняли, что от Вас требует преподаватель. А что он требует – я описывал в ответе.

Comment: `объединить 2 класса типа Enemy в один, для более удобного использования... для более правильной иерархии` — правильная иерархия — это как раз два разных класса для разных типов объектов. Может быть, выделить из них общий класс `Enemy` нужно?

Comment: @post_zeew прав — "объединить классы в один абстрактный" это не то же самое, что сделать один класс из двух. Почитайте про абстрактные классы и вы поймёте.